# Dispose process with unknown runtime remaining

Tags: c#, phantomjs

I have a round-robin system of long-running processes that need to be disposed and re-started after 100 rounds each, as the executable has memory leaks (`phantomjs.exe`).
The remaining runtime on killing the process is unknown and it has to finish running. A max. estimate of say 15 seconds is good enough.

So far I do this

```
// p refers to a model which has a property System.Diagnostics.Process process

var p = _processes[_nextProcess];

if (p.callCount > _maxCalls)
{
    _discardedProcesses.Add(p);
    _processes[_nextProcess] = new PhantomProcessModel(...);
    p.Destroy(_discardedProcesses);
}
```

and

```
public class PhantomProcessModel
{
    ...

    public Process process { get; set; }

    public int callCount { get; set; }

    public void Destroy(List<PhantomProcessModel> discardedProcesses)
    {
        //process.WaitForExit(15000);
        // or timer or different thread
        process.Close();
        process.Dispose();
        discardedProcesses.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

The process killing in `void Destroy()` has to account for these issues:

1. It must not block until the timer finishes, e.g. 15 sec
2. It must not be garbage collected until the timeout is over.
3. Finally it has to disappear without memory leaks.

What is a proper way to achieve that? Is my approach OK?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reading [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Well yes, WaitForExit should run on a different Thread or simply be a timer. I'm more worried about the overall mechanism. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What should happen if the process doesn't terminate after 15 seconds?

Comment: The process is actually always terminated from the C# side. WaitForExit does the same as Thread.Sleep in this case. The process serves local http requests from different class instances. So waiting 15 sec is a simplification to ensure the last request has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive implementation could leverage the [threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx).

```
public void Destroy(List<PhantomProcessModel> discardedProcesses)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( (someobj) => 
    {
        process.WaitForExit(15000);
        process.Close();
        process.Dispose();
        // instance members of List<> are not thread safe
        lock(discardedProcesses) 
        {
            discardedProcesses.Remove(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the use of the discardedProcesses list required against garbage collection or are there better ways?

Comment: No, not really. The threadpool queue keeps an reference to the object and keeps it alive. After the queued anonymous method has finished and assuming no other references are kept, the object becomes a candidate for GC.